# not a valid choice in django restframework serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

i set my post model with choice and migrate model.
after that i create postserializer for create
and i run the server and post with data in postman for test,
but i got the 'is not a valid choice' err on serializer.

here is my model,

```
class Post(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('mc', 'MIRACLE'),
        ('hw', 'HOMEWORK')
    )
    title    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    content  = models.TextField()
    author   = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializer,

```
class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

view

```
class PostAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        data = {
            'title'   :request.data['title'],
            'category':request.data['category'],
            'content' :request.data['content'],
            'author'  :request.user.id
        }
        serializer = PostCreateSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        else:
            print(serializer.erros)
        
        ...
```

and request data (in Postman)

```
{
    'title':'test_title',
    'category':'HOMEWORK',
    'content':'test_content'
}
```

result is

```
{'category': [ErrorDetail(string='"HOMEWORK" is not a valid choice.', code='invalid_choice')]}
```

i tried request with changing category 'HOMEWORK' to 'hw'
then it works
but i want request with large one

Answer (score 0):

Your error on serialize level. Try this

```
readable_to_choice = {"HOMEWORK": "hw", "MIRACLE": "mc"}
data = {'title'   :request.data['title'],
        'category': readable_to_choice.get(request.data['category']),
        'content' :request.data['content'],
        'author'  :request.user.id}
serializer = PostCreateSerializer(data=data)
```

UPD: you should make your api func like this:

```
serializer = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
print(serializer.data) # do logic with that data
```

and try to override `to_internal_value` method in your serializer. for example:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
  readable_to_choice = {"HOMEWORK": "hw", "MIRACLE": "mc"}
  data["category"] = readable_to_choice.get(data["category"])
  res = super().to_internal_value(data)
  return res
```

I think this way is more accurate

Comment: is there a another way without reverse the choices??

Comment: @ysJ Updated look.